# Update text field item in list 2 from text field value in list 1

Tags: sharepoint-designer, updatelistitems

[image]List #1: If CurrentItem:EmployeeStatus equals Active Employee (I just clicked String Builder and typed in Active Employee)

Update item in (list #2 called Irvine-First Day) to Active Employee (blank text field I want to update to say Active Employee)

Is my Update List Item filled out correctly? I guess I don't understand the difference between the Add field/value at the top, and the Field/Value under Find List Item. They seem to me to be the same thing and I do always get the warning about "The lookup that you defined is not guaranteed to return a single value. If more than one value is returned, only the first value will be used. Do you want to continue?"   I don't understand what that means either.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field-value list at the top is where you specify which field(s) you want to update with which value(s).

The find the list item at the bottom is where you specify how to find the list item to update.

If you specify fieldX/valueX at the top and fieldY/valueY at the bottom it's similar to the SQL statement

```
UPDATE list
   SET fieldX=valueX
 WHERE fieldY=valueY
```

(except that only the first found item will be updated)

Your current entry specify find the first item where `Employee Status` is `Active Employee` and set `Employee Status` to `Active Employee`, which almost certainly isn't what you want. You need to change the bottom part to specify how to find the item to update.

The warning comes when the query you specify (at the bottom) isn't on a unique column, so there might be multiple items which fullfil the query.

Comment: OK that makes a little more sense-- thanks Per! So the stop should be my target list (Irvine-First Day) and the bottom should be the source list (CurrentItem:EmployeeStatus) it sounds like. I will try that. Thank you very much.

Comment: More likely employee name/id = (CurrentItem:Employee name/id)

Comment: name/id? from the target list?

Comment: I did get it working- thank you. I made "Full Name" a unique column so top says my list #2 (target list) Irvine-First Day > Field: Employee Status  Value: Active Employee, and the bottom (Find the List Item) (used to just identify the list, I guess?) says: Field: Full Name, Value: CurrentItem:FullName      Thanks a million for your help.